# Apache Flink - Serialize json and perform join operation

Tags: join, stream, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to use Jackson library to read a String from Kafka topic and perform a join from another stream.

Here is a sample code with two streams of data. I want to perform join operation on these to message stream.

Say for example, the incoming streams are:

```
messageStream1 = {"A":"a"}
messageStream2 = {"B":"a"}
```

Join criteria is `messageStream1."A" = messageStream2."B"`. How do I implement this in Flink?

DataStream 1:

```java
DataStream<String> messageStream1 = env.addSource(
  new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<String>("input", new SimpleStringSchema() , parameterTool.getProperties()));

messageStream1.map(new MapFunction<String, JsonNode>() {
    @Override
    public JsonNode map(String value) throws Exception {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        try {
            JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(value);
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
            while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
                System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
            }
            return rootNode;
        }catch (java.io.IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

DataStream 2:

```java
DataStream<String> messageStream2 = env.addSource(
  new FlinkKafkaConsumer082<String>("input", new SimpleStringSchema() , parameterTool.getProperties()));

messageStream2.map(new MapFunction<String, JsonNode>() {
    @Override
    public JsonNode map(String value) throws Exception {
        JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
        try {
            JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(value);
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String,JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
            while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String,JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
                System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
            }
            return rootNode;
        }catch (java.io.IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract the key field into an extra attribute, such that Flink can access it (an alternative would be to provide an custom key selector: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/programming_guide.html#specifying-keys).

Thus, your return type of the `map(...)` might be `Tuple2<String,JsonNode>` (if `String` is the correct type of your join attribute).

Then, you can specify your join as described in the documentation (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/streaming_guide.html):

```java
messageStream1.join(messageStream2)
    .where(0).equalTo(0) // both zeros indicate that the join happens on the zero's attribute, ie, the String attribute of Tuple2
    .window(TumblingTimeWindows.of(Time.of(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
    .apply(new JoinFunction() {...});
```

In order to perform a join using `DataStream` API, you also need to specify a **join window**. Only tuples that belong to the same window can be joined.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I dont have a set structure on input data. All I know is that it is a JSON. If this is the case, do I need to resort to reflection to kind of auto create the object on the fly? I understand that there could be overhead because of this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you got two stream of JSON object and want to join both. Thus, you expect that each object has at least a fixed field "X" with know type "T" you wanna use for the join. Thus, you can extract "X" and put it into a Tuple2 which holds the key and the whole JSON in its two attributes. Or might it be possible, that some objects so not contain "X"? If yes, what would be your strategy to deal with those?

Comment: You are right. Let me rephrase it a little bit.
Stream1 = {"A":"a", "B":"b"}
Stream2 = {"B":"a","X":"x"}
Given that these are the 2 streams, if I have to join on Stream1.A=Stream2.B
If I get you right, map function should return tuple with <String,String..>?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. It seems that in your example, you show only one tuple per stream. If we assume that A and B are the field you wanna join on, map would transform the JSON  `{"A":"a", "B":"b"}` to `<"a",  {"A":"a", "B":"b"}>` (ie, a `Tuple2<String, JsonNode>`). Similar for stream2 `{"B":"a","X":"x"}` is transformed into `<"a", {"B":"a","X":"x"}>`. So, you only extract the key field value, and emit the key together with the complete JSON object.

Comment: Sorry .. it took a little time to respond. Thanks for the explanation. I was way off on my understanding. Thanks again.